# Replaces spaces with NAN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns:

```
Name        Name2           DateTime
                            2016-06-10 05:22
                            2016-06-10 05:23
                            2016-06-10 14:25
Guest       Guest1          2016-06-10 15:32
```

I have to replace empty spaces with NAN. So AccountName and AccountName2 of rows 1,2,3 and 4 should be NAN. I tried the below statement:

```
 df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].replace(r'[^\s+]',np.nan, regex=True)
```

But since I have white spaces after "Guest   " in Name, all 5 rows get replaced with NAN.

Edit:

This is our actual data.

```
Name              Name2                  DateTime
\t\t-\r\n\t      \t\t-\r\n\t            2016-06-10 05:22
\t\t-\r\n\t      \t\t-\r\n\t            2016-06-10 05:23
\t\t-\r\n\t      \t\t-\r\n\t            2016-06-10 14:25
\t\tGuest\r\n\t  \t\tGuest1\r\n\t       2016-06-10 15:32
```

I used this to remove those escape characters.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('\r','').str.replace('\t','').str.replace('\n','').str.replace('-','')
```

After removing those characters, I am not sure what gets inserted in that place now.

Comment: You could strip the spaces and then replace `df['Name'].str.strip().replace(r'[^\s+]',np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: df['Name'] is of type float64. I am trying to convert it to string and then replace it but I am unsuccessful still.

Comment: how can it be float64 when you have strings?

Comment: @jezrael: I have edited the question

Comment: Do u need to keep the spaces in the guest names?

Comment: @Yarnspinner: No there is no need of spaces. Just the text is enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution which found `length` of data and then by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) replacing all data with length `0` or `1`:

```
print (df.applymap(len))
   Name  Name2  DateTime
0     0      0        16
1     0      0        16
2     0      0        16
3     5      6        16

df[df.applymap(len) < 2] = np.nan
print (df)
    Name   Name2          DateTime
0    NaN     NaN  2016-06-10 05:22
1    NaN     NaN  2016-06-10 05:23
2    NaN     NaN  2016-06-10 14:25
3  Guest  Guest1  2016-06-10 15:32
```

Comment: Super. I am very happy, because I once do similar replacing and it was horror.

Comment: Yeah it was pulling my leg since yesterday, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont need the spaces, this should work.

```
df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].replace('[\s]+',"", regex=True) #Gets rid of all blank spaces
df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].replace('',np.nan, regex=True) #Replace completely empty cells with nan
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there won't be spaces between the names, you could use `.strip()` to remove any whitespace (or anything, really) off the ends of the string.

```
 df3['Name'] = df3['Name'].strip().replace(r'[^\s+]',np.nan, regex=True)
```

Comment: `strip` is not a method for a `Series` `str.strip` is and it requires the dtype to be `str` which the OP has already indicated it is not

Comment: Ah I see what the problem is. Maybe you could try using [`DataFrame.applymap()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) and map each element using a function that strips the string, then replaces with nan.